# How to know what view i should display

Tags: android, user-interface, android-view

I have a user sign-in layout when the user clicks the sign-in there will be two possible layouts.

The 1st one would be the dashboard(***layout A***) with a button to time-in then if clicked it would open another layout(***layout B***).

The 2nd possible layout is when the time-in have already been click it will automatically show the layout **B**.

**Button onClickEvent in layout A:**

```
case R.id.dashboard_btn_login:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, listviewscreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("login", value); 
            Dashboard.this.startActivity(intent);
            //should make a flag here that i have sent it to listviewscreen

            break;
```

**Code for sign-in layout when clicking sign-in**

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.loginscreen_btn_login:
            checkInput();
            break;
    }

}
private void checkInput(){
    username = userET.getText().toString();
    password = passET.getText().toString();
    if(username.equals("admin")){
        if(password.equals("admin")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
            intent.putExtra("login", value); //Optional parameters
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

how should i get the flag that layout A send?

Comment: if you show your code , may be it solved

Comment: I just used the time in to know if the button was click. **if** time-in is not yet set then open layoutA **else** layoutB

Comment: use share prefernce as @febi said , it solve your problem OR you want more info than post your code here . So we have idea what you did .

Comment: ill try to post it later then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save a boolean value in SharedPreference once you enter the Layout A. So check while user click on sign in whether that boolean is already set and show the corresponding layout.

Comment: Apparently i really need to use the shared preference for this because if i use a variable it will be destroyed upon closing the app. Thank you Febi Mathew